Leaky abstraction with setters and getters in js/ts
I am working on a game. Because I don't want to marry frameworks, I wrote an abstraction for the graphics engine and am now trying to shoehorn three.js into it.
I am working with gl-matrix for vector math (using vec3, typed arrays), three.js has its own vector classes (using {x:number, y:number, z:number}). My interface for a 3d object looks as follows:
interface Thing{
    ...
    position:vec3
}

and my implementation looks like this:
class ThreeJsThing implements Thing{
    ...
    set position(p:vec3){
        this.mesh.position.set(p[0], p[1], p[2]) // [,,] -> {xyz}
    }
    get position(){
        let p = this.mesh.position
        return vec3.fromValues(p.x, p.y, p.z) // {xyz} -> [,,]
    }
}

Now it's all fun and games until someone tries to do:
let myThing = new ThreeJsThing()
myThing.position[1] = 5 // only changes a temporary copy that is returned by the getter

And with gl-matrix this is especially a problem because it uses output parameters for performance reasons, internally doing that array assignment above:
vec3.add(myThing.position, a, b)

I know how to work around this problem because I am (now) aware of it, but other contributors are probably also going to choke on this, especially since it fails silently. Just from a clean code point of view, I can't really pinpoint where I used anti-patterns or bad design or something. I find ThreeJsThing to be as faithful to the interface as possible. I have some suspicions:

maybe this is just a general problem with set and get and they should be avoided?
maybe set and get should not do copies and only accept/return and internally work with references of the same type?
output parameters are frowned upon (but then myThing.position[1] = 5 is still a problem)

Any advice appreciated.
EDIT:
While I do appreciate remarks on the context, I provided it to show what lead me to this problem. I consider this to be a broader problem that I would like to pinpoint so I know how and when to avoid it in other contexts.
Judging from the comments, the crux seems to be that I should not use get when it returns a mutable copy, since it looks like a regular writable member from the outside. Are there more gotchas to be aware of with getters and setters?
I would consider this on a level with Python's mutable defaults, I find it easy to run into and not very obvious... I wonder why this isn't mentioned anywhere...

What exactly is the vec3 type? Why does it have writable properties if you don't want that?

"I don't want to marry frameworks, I wrote an abstraction for the graphics engine" - well now you're married to your own in-house abstraction, which probably has a worse design and documentation than any framework you could have chosen :P Especially if there are other contributors who need to work with the homegrown solution and learn about details like this.

The basic problem is having a getter that returns temporary mutable objects.

(a)Bergi: https://glmatrix.net/docs/vec3.js.html
(a)Bergi: yes but maybe at some point I want to switch to babylon.js, then I just have to build a new wrapper instead of doing surgery on every file.
@Barmar is there a way to annotate the returned reference as const? Or should I just avoid such a getter when it can't return a proper reference?
(I can only use one @ and Barmar was more helpful)

I would recommend dropping gl-matrix – any (theoretical!) performance obtained by in-place operations is lost by making a copy to do the “in-place” operations on. Just use Three.js’s vector and matrix types; you can keep their interface even if you replace Three.js later on. (Also, if this is TypeScript and you’re open to enforcing constraints with types only, you should tag that.)

@Mircode I guess you should at least return a ReadonlyVec3 from your getter then. Also if you want to be able to switch to babylon, build it as a backend for your abstraction right now (i.e. implement BabylonThing) and keep testing it so that your abstraction doesn't (by accident) start incorporating three.js idiosyncrasies.

@Ry- you are right that in this particular case there is no performance benefit. I am using gl-matrix because it's a small and concise vector math library and I do lots of vector operations everywhere else as well. Furthermore, p2.js (which I am also wrapping) also uses gl-matrix, so if I switch to {x:y:z:} vectors, I'd have the same problem there.

@Bergi thanks for the suggestions! Gonna try to wrap babylon as well. Also, I didn't know that ReadonlyVec3 was a thing in gl-matrix. But that means I have to change the interface to setPosition(p:vec3) and getPosition():ReadonlyVec3, which is probably fine.

You can change the setter as well, given it only reads from the vector.

Solution suggested in the comments:
// gl-matrix
type vec3 = [number, number, number] | Float32Array;
type ReadonlyVec3 = readonly [number, number, number] | Float32Array;
// three.js
type Vector3 = {x:number, y:number, z:number}

interface Thing{
    setPosition(p:ReadonlyVec3): void
    getPosition():ReadonlyVec3
}

class ThreeJsThing implements Thing{
    private position:Vector3 = {x:0, y:0, z:0}
    setPosition(p:ReadonlyVec3){
        // actually this.position.set(p[0], p[1], p[2])
        this.position.x = p[0]
        this.position.y = p[1]
        this.position.z = p[2]
    }
    getPosition(){
        // actually return vec3.fromValues(...) as const
        return [
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.position.z
        ] as const
    }
}

let thing = new ThreeJsThing()
let position = [1, 2, 3] as vec3
thing.setPosition(position)
console.log(thing.getPosition())
console.log(thing.getPosition()[1])
// position = thing.getPosition() // Type 'readonly [...]' is not assignable to type 'vec3'.
// thing.getPosition()[1] = 5 // Cannot assign to '1' because it is a read-only property.

Here is another solution that was posted by KLASANGUI, got downvoted into oblivion and then deleted. Use with caution, it probably opens a whole nother can of worms and blows up at three more places but I consider it absolutely valid and a beautiful JavaScript flex. It completely solves every problem I stated without syntactic sugar compromises.
// gl-matrix
type vec3 = [number, number, number] | Float32Array;
type ReadonlyVec3 = readonly [number, number, number] | Float32Array;
// three.js
type Vector3 = { x: number, y: number, z: number }

interface Thing {
    position: vec3
}

class ThreeJsThing implements Thing {
    #position: Vector3 = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }

    set position(p: vec3) {
        this.#position.x = p[0]
        this.#position.y = p[1]
        this.#position.z = p[2]
    }

    get position() {
        let p = this.#position
        const accessor = {
            length: 3,
            set 0(x:number) { p.x = x },
            get 0() { return p.x },
            set 1(y:number) { p.y = y },
            get 1() { return p.y },
            set 2(z:number) { p.z = z },
            get 2() { return p.z }
        };
        Object.setPrototypeOf(accessor, Array.prototype);
        return accessor as vec3
    }
}

let thing = new ThreeJsThing()
let position = [1, 2, 3] as vec3
thing.position = position
thing.position[1] = 5
position = thing.position
console.log(position)

